# Reset label position before animation is applied (swift3)

Tags: ios, animation, swift3, label, reset

My code below moves the label north. I would like to create a another button that resets label before the animation was trigger. I know I could just recreate the animation in reverse but that seems inefficient.

```
   @IBAction func press(_ sender: Any) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 10, animations: {
        self.label.frame.origin.y -= 500
    }, completion: nil )
}
   @IBAction func reset(_ sender: Any) {
  //reset the "label" position
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```
 //To store the default value of the position of the label
   var yPosLabel : CGFloat!
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        yPosLabel = self.myLabel.frame.origin.y
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

 @IBAction func reset(_ sender: Any) {
 //Just in case you are using AutoLayout
 self.view. translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
 let newFrame = CGRect(x:self.label.frame.origin.x, y:yPosLabel, 
 width:self.label.frame.size.width, height:self.label.frame.size.height)
 self.label.frame = newFrame
 }
```

Hope this helps. Happy Coding.